# CMake compare_files sorted

Tags: cmake

In my workflow the generated files are stored with the source code to support another ancient build system (which can't be fixed and it won't go away because reasons).

So, the CMake build just uses `cmake -E compare_files ...` to check that the WSDL gives the same *.h and *.cpp files.

KDSoap with its `kdwsdl2cpp` generator is not producing a stable output: the order of the classes can be different from invocation to invocation.

That breaks the check. One option is to sort the lines of the files before the comparison. Is there a portable way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a CMake script for that:

```
# Input variables: FILE1 and FILE2.
# Returns 0 if files are the same after sort.

cmake_policy(SET CMP0007 NEW)

file(STRINGS ${FILE1} v1)
file(STRINGS ${FILE2} v2)
list(SORT v1)
list(SORT v2)

if(NOT v1 STREQUAL v2)
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Files '${FILE1}' and  '${FILE2}' are not equal." )
endif(NOT v1 STREQUAL v2)
```

And use it with `COMMAND` in something like `add_custom_target`:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFILE1=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.cpp -DFILE2=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo_generated.cpp -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SortCompareFiles.cmake
```

Comment: And you actually need to put that script into separate file and call it at compile time?